# Repeated Measures ANOVA unequal samples

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, paired-data

I am having a problem with choosing an appropriate test for the following data (I won't put them here, just describe them):

The experiment is on the effects of reactive oxygen species on samples of phytoplankton. I had one control and three treatments. I can use one-way ANOVAs to assess the between treatment differences in the biomass and cell number of different phytoplankton groups with no problem (because the assumption of independence of measure is met as they are within different tanks). But for within treatment assessments this assumption is not met, because the plankton community on day two depends on the community on day one and so on.

The issue I am having is that from my admittedly limited understanding of repeated measures ANOVA (and paired samples t-tests), I would need to have the same participants (species) across all collection dates in order for an assessment to be made of the effects of the reactive oxygen species. The problem is that the ROS kill specific species so as the experiment progresses the species number decreases.

I have found a few papers in similar topics that use this means of analysis but I do not get how they could if the species number varies :(

I can just plug the data into SPSS and it will analyse it for me. The question I have then is whether this data is valid, is if not, why not?